# Arch D paper size not in PapersizeEnum of Windows?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, printing

I can't find the Arch D papersize in any enum. Can Someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom page size like shown in the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743179/programatically-setting-printer-page-size

**Update:** Since the linked question is deleted and the answer was external link only, here the embedded code on how to create a custom page Size:

```
printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("PaperArchD",42,66);
```

Obviously the dimensions need to be adjusted for whatever the real Arch D size is.

Comment: That question is no more (and the answer there was just an external link anyway).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Good point, added the code directly